# Efficiently converting a matrix of values into many rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in pandas, collected raw from the source:

[image]

I am interested in efficiently converting this into the following format:

[image]

Is there an efficient way to do this in Pandas? I can hack at it through loops but I'd like to use something inbuilt if possible. The order of the rows doesn't matter.

Comment: [`df.melt('Year')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: Too easy. Thanks.